# CORS working in IE but not in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax

I did a Web service and now I am consuming it from different servers. It works fine in IE, however if I try it in Firefox or Chrome I always get the same error:
**500 internal server error**

This is my AJAX code:
$.support.cors = true;

```
        $.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,

            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:52350/CSJMSGovernWebServiceDMZ.asmx/GetStreets",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "{'streetname':'" + value + "', 'streetno':'', 'orderby':''}"
        })
        .then( function ( response ) {
            $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                $.each(val, function( key, value ) {
                    var valor = value.Shortdescription;
                    html += "<li><a href='#'>" + valor + "</a></li>";
                });
            });
            $ul.html( html );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
        });
```

Of course, I wrote this in my server:

```
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="content-type" />
```

Any advice will be welcome.
Many Thanks!

Comment: The only problem i see is your json is invalid, but... that shouldn't make it work in IE and not chrome. How are you defining `value`? have you confirmed that it contains what you expect it to?

Comment: Have you debugged the server-side code to see where the 500 is coming from? Also, don't create json strings via concatenation. Create a javascript object and pass it to `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: This works fine on the same dominion. I tried it in IE, Chrome and Firefox and works fine on all of them. So, I can suspect it is a CORS issue.